# Slim app (PHP) : Need to store persistent/cache data

Tags: php, rest, caching, slim, restful-architecture

I have to develop a `RESTful API` for an Android app and have decided to go with PHP using the slim framework.

Some background, currently every time the client app makes a request, the server does some DB operations and creates a payload. This was causing high load on the server during peak hours of app use. So I'm looking for a way to cache this payload and have it available whenever the request comes. This cache will have to updated rarely compared to the number of reads (Only on DB change by admin).

To test this I tried the following code,

In index.php

```
$app->flag = 1;
```

And the endpoint

```
$app->get("/getContent", function() use ($app){
    if($app->flag == 1){
        echo 'Changing value';
        $app->flag = 0;
        return;
    }
    echo $app->folder;
});
```

The ideal case would be if it prints "Changing value" first time and 0 thereafter. But the value of '`$app->flag`' is always `1`, at the start of the endpoint. How can I persist the data between successive calls to the end point?

Also, would it be better if I store the payload in a file each time and do an I/O to handle the endpoint request (Will this throw an I/O exception if the admin tried to update the file while the endpoint is reading it for the client)?

I'm fairly new to PHP, will really appreciate your insight or even other ideas to do the same from you.

Comment: You could try to use a key/value cache like php-apcu (uses the same interface as the old php-apc for the key/value caching). This saves the cache in memory instead of a file (which is much much much slower). You can read more here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.apcu.php

Comment: what is the data structure and type?

Comment: Provided the data is updated rarely and the problem exists only on peak hours, why not use [HTTP caching](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/features/caching.html)?

Comment: @krasipenkov It'll be 7 or 8 json arrays with text data (~100KB each)

Comment: @GeorgyIvanov I'd prefer having it cached from update to update because each request would use a different combination of the cached data, and they're uniformly spread out through the day, peak time of about 5 hours

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I think I will go with ACPu, fits the job well. Do you think storing close to an MB of json data would pose an issue?

Comment: No, that shouldn't be an issue, unless you're running the script on a server with unreasonably low amount of memory. Just make sure to check the APCu configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my suggestions:

1. Can you use memcache for storing the data? You do the DB operations and processing once, then build json and store it in memcache (which stores data directly in memory, and as a plus you would avoid I/O operations)
2. Do all the DB processing, build json and save it in another table (used for caching results). The main concern with this approach is the number of users hitting your DB at once. Although it will be simple reads and for sure the query result will be cached by DB engine natively you must consider the number of DB connections used at a time